# scala lower bound should allow same hierarchy Objects?

Tags: scala, lower-bound

I have just started Scala and want to clear some basics. In the function below Lower bound is set to Puppy. How come Puppy1 and Puppy2 is allowed in the below code.

```
class Animal
class Dog extends Animal
class Puppy extends Animal
class Puppy1 extends Animal
class Puppy2 extends Puppy

class AnimalCarer{
    def display [T >: Puppy](t: T){
    println(t)
    }
}

val animal = new Animal
val dog = new Dog
val puppy = new Puppy
val puppy1 = new Puppy1
val puppy2 = new Puppy2

val animalCarer = new AnimalCarer
animalCarer.display(animal)
animalCarer.display(puppy)
animalCarer.display(puppy1)
animalCarer.display(puppy2)
animalCarer.display(dog)
```

Comment: I thing `T` filled with `Object` here.

Comment: The compiler up-casts to a type that fits the bounds, if it can.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't fill in `T` explicitly, the compiler attempts to infers it for you with the right types to make this compile:

```
animalCarer.display[testing.ParamTest.Animal](ParamTest.this.puppy1);
animalCarer.display[testing.ParamTest.Puppy](ParamTest.this.puppy2);
animalCarer.display[testing.ParamTest.Animal](ParamTest.this.dog)
```

This is part of Scala's [Local Type Inference](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/local-type-inference.html) algorithm. As you see, each method call is infered the right `T`, for example, `puppy1: Animal`, which adheres to the lower bounds constraint.

Answer (score 1):

This one is classic example of Scala type inference messing up with the common notion (intuition).

```
def foo[T >: Puppy](t: T) = t

foo(new Puppy1) //compiles

foo[Puppy1](new Puppy1) //give compilation error
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> def foo[T >: Puppy](t: T) = t
foo: [T >: Puppy](t: T)T

scala> foo(new Puppy1)
res9: Animal = Puppy1@4d49af10

scala> foo[Puppy1](new Puppy1)
<console>:16: error: type arguments [Puppy1] do not conform to method foo's type parameter bounds [T >: Puppy]
       foo[Puppy1](new Puppy1)
      ^
```